# Invertible derivative operator

Tags: functional-analysis, general-topology, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I have been looking for a Banach space $X$ and a subspace $D$ of $X$ such that the operator derivative
$$
\partial:D\longrightarrow X
$$
is invertible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know the terminology. What is the operator derivative?

Comment: For example if $f\in C^1([0,1])$, then $\partial f=f'$

Comment: For instance, take $X = \{ f \in C([0,1]): f(1) = 0\}$ and $D = \{f \in C^1([0,1]): \; f \in X, \; f' \in X\}$ and $\partial f = f'$. I think this question rather belongs to Math StackExchange.

Comment: Thank you very much